# XSLT: Walking a tree-like structure

Tags: xml, xslt, tree

I have an xml document, that has a list of categories:

```
<categories>
    <category id="1" parent="0">Configurations</category>
    <category id="11" parent="13">LCD Monitor</category>
    <category id="12" parent="13">CRT Monitor</category>
    <category id="13" parent="1"">Monitors</category>
    <category id="123" parent="122">Printer</category>
    ...
</categories>
```

And a list of products:

```
<products>
  <product>
    ...
   <category>12</category>
    ...
  </product>
    ...
</products>
```

If product's category is equal to 12, then it should be transformed to "Configurations/Monitors/CRT Monitor" (take category 12, then it's parent (13), etc.). If parent is 0, stop.

Is there an elegant way to do this using a XSL Transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether this would be considered elegant, but with this input:

```
<root>
    <categories>
        <category id="1" parent="0">Configurations</category>
        <category id="11" parent="13">LCD Monitor</category>
        <category id="12" parent="13">CRT Monitor</category>
        <category id="13" parent="1">Monitors</category>
        <category id="123" parent="122">Printer</category>
    </categories>
    <products>
        <product>
             <category>12</category>
        </product>
        <product>
             <category>11</category>
        </product>
     </products>
</root>
```

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//product"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product">
  <product>
    <path>
      <xsl:call-template name="catwalk">
        <xsl:with-param name="id"><xsl:value-of select="category"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </path>
  </product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="catwalk">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <xsl:if test="$id != '0'">
    <xsl:call-template name="catwalk">
      <xsl:with-param name="id"><xsl:value-of select="//category[@id = $id]/@parent"/>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="//category[@id = $id]"/><xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will give you this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
  <product>
    <path>Configurations/Monitors/CRT Monitor/
    </path>
  </product>
  <product>
     <path>Configurations/Monitors/LCD Monitor/
     </path>
  </product>
  </root>
```

The paths still have an extra trailing slash, you'd need another little bit of conditional XSLT to make the slash only get emitted when you aren't at the first level.

It is vital that you category hierarchy is correct, otherwise your transform can easily get into an endless loop that will only stop when it runs out of memory. If I was implementing something like this in a real system I'd be tempted to add a parameter to the catWalk template that incremented on each call and add it to the test so it stopped looping after 10 calls whether or not the parent had been found.

Answer (score 3):

The use of an `<xsl:key>` is advisable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="category" match="categories/category" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//products/product" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('category', category)" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:if test="@parent &gt; 0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('category', @parent)" />
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
Configurations/Monitors/LCD Monitor
Configurations/Monitors/CRT Monitor
```

when tested on the following XML:

```
<data>
  <categories>
    <category id="1" parent="0">Configurations</category>
    <category id="11" parent="13">LCD Monitor</category>
    <category id="12" parent="13">CRT Monitor</category>
    <category id="13" parent="1">Monitors</category>
    <category id="123" parent="122">Printer</category>
  </categories>
  <products>
    <product>
      <category>11</category>
    </product>
    <product>
      <category>12</category>
    </product>
  </products>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close enough (I've stuggled with putting xslt code here, so I've escaped it, hopefully that works ok

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="OutputCategoryTree">
      <xsl:with-param name="productId" select="12"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="OutputCategoryTree">
    <xsl:param name="productId"/>
    <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="/categories/category[@id=$productId]/@parent"/>
    <xsl:if test="$parentId!=0"> 
      <xsl:call-template name="OutputCategoryTree">
        <xsl:with-param name="productId" select="/categories/category[@id=$productId]/@parent"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>/
    <xsl:value-of select="/categories/category[@id=$productId]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry for the rough sample code, but it does generate

> /Configurations/Monitors/CRT Monitor

Answer (score 1):

You might consider starting by transforming your categories document from a flat list of nodes to a hierarchy.  That simplifies the problem of transforming your input document considerably.  Also, if your list of products is large, it will perform much better than an approach that searches the flat list of categories for every step in the category hierarchy.

```
<xsl:template match="categories">
    <categories>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="category[@parent='0']"/>
    </categories>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
    <category id='{@id}'>
       <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="/categories/category[@parent=current()/@id]"/>
    </category>
</xsl:template>
```

This will produce something like this:

```
<categories>
    <category id="1">Configurations
       <category id="13">Monitors
          <category id="11">LCD Monitor</category>
           <category id="12">CRT Monitor</category>
       </category>
    </category>
    ...
</categories>
```

Assuming you've passed the transformed categories document into your XSLT as a parameter (or read it into a variable using the `document()` function), the template for products becomes pretty simple:

```
<xsl:template match="product"/>
   <xsl:variable name="c" select="$categories/categories/category[@id=current()/category]"/>
   <xsl:foreach select="$c/ancestor-or-self::category">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
         <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:foreach>
</xsl:template>
```